# What does a "torus obtained by identifying each of the three pairs of opposite edges of a regular hexagon" look like? What is it called?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, terminology, eisenstein-integers

Wikipedia's [Eisenstein integer; Quotient of C by the Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer#Quotient_of_C_by_the_Eisenstein_integers) says:

> The quotient of the complex plane C by the lattice containing all Eisenstein integers is a complex torus of real dimension 2. This is one of two tori with maximal symmetry among all such complex tori.<sup>[citation needed]</sup> This torus can be obtained by identifying each of the three pairs of opposite edges of a regular hexagon. (The other maximally symmetric torus is the quotient of the complex plane by the additive lattice of Gaussian integers, and can be obtained by identifying each of the two pairs of opposite sides of a square fundamental domain, such as [0,1] × [0,1].)

I understand how identifying each of the *two pairs* of opposite edges of a *rectangle* makes a "normal torus" or donut, but I can't visualize what this torus might look like.

Does this torus have a name? Can it be illustrated?

Comment: The image is copied in the answer itself.

Comment: And there is no particular term. Any topological space homeomorphic to THE torus $S^1 \times S^1$ is called A torus.

Comment: @LeeMosher wait, I understand the drawing! I'm good.

Comment: Great, good to hear!

Comment: @LeeMosher I've just asked [Does any polygon with side number 2n >= 2 form a torus when all pairs of opposite sides are joined? (works for n=2, 3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4088573/284619)