# Does any polygon with side number $2n$ with $n \ge 2$ form a torus when all pairs of opposite sides are joined? (works for n=2, 3)

Tags: geometry

Wikipedia's [Eisenstein integer; Quotient of C by the Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer#Quotient_of_C_by_the_Eisenstein_integers) says:

> The quotient of the complex plane C by the lattice containing all Eisenstein integers is a complex torus of real dimension 2. This is one of two tori with maximal symmetry among all such complex tori.<sup>[citation needed]</sup> This torus can be obtained by identifying each of the three pairs of opposite edges of a regular hexagon. (The other maximally symmetric torus is the quotient of the complex plane by the additive lattice of Gaussian integers, and can be obtained by identifying each of the two pairs of opposite sides of a square fundamental domain, such as [0,1] × [0,1].)

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53459/284619) explains and shows how identifying opposite sides of a hexagon produces a torus, as do answers to [What surface do we get by joining the opposite edges of a hexagon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1978562/284619)

**Question:** Bringing opposite sides of a quadrilateral and a hexagon both produce a torus. Does any polygon side number $2n$ with $n \ge 2$ form a torus when all pairs of opposite sides are joined?

---

From the linked answer:

> [image: from http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Winter2009/Victor/part1.htm]
>
> Image source: [http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Winter2009/Victor/part1.htm](http://www.math.cornell.edu/%7Emec/Winter2009/Victor/part1.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "no" for the very next case $n=4$. In fact the answer is "no" for all cases $n \ge 4$.

I will assume that your intention is to glue opposite sides by a translation isometry of the plane; or to put it another way, to glue them using matching arrows that point in the same direction on the plane, but in opposite directions around the periphery of the polygon. It follows from this assumption that the quotient surface is orientable.

In that case, let me describe what happens in two cases, depending on whether $n$ is even or odd. The outline is: count the vertex cycles; use that to compute the Euler characteristic; and then apply the classification of surfaces.

Here's the outcome:

- If $n=2g$ is even, then the $2n$ vertices form $1$ vertex cycle (generalizing the case of the square). The quotient therefore has $1$ vertex, $n$ edges, and $1$ face, thus has Euler characteristic $1-n+1=2-2g$. From the classification of surfaces, it follows that the quotient surface is homeomorphic to the orientable surface of genus $g$.
- If $n=2g+1$ is odd, then the $2n$ vertices form two vertex cycles (generalizing the case of the hexagon). The quotient surface therefore has $2$ vertices, $n$ edges, and $1$ face, thus has Euler characteristic $2-n+1 = 2-2g$, and again is homeomorphic to the surface of genus $g$.

So to answer your question: No, not in general. The only cases where opposite side gluing gives the torus are the two cases you know, the square and the hexagon.

Generalizing from $n=2,3$ to all $n \ge 2$ is fraught with peril!

Comment: Thanks! Yes my plan was to apply the arrows and gluing as shown in the hexagon drawing, but seeing [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088573/does-any-polygon-with-side-number-2n-with-n-ge-2-form-a-torus-when-all-pair/4089030#comment8449260_4088621) one can point all arrows "counterclockwise" and match them up that way. I assume that would have a different result. Do you think that case needs a new question?

Comment: That's quite different, and leads to a non-orientable surface. I wouldn't say it *needs* a new question, because there is another option: read up on the proof of the classification of surfaces. That would answer all of your questions.

Comment: Got it. I believe there have been some good answers to questions like [How to start reading topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2311958/284619) and especially [Can anybody recommend me a topology textbook?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150556/284619) and I've math libraries available. I've been away from using math for many decades and [sphere eversion](https://mathoverflow.net/q/246851/96907) is essentially now a "bucket list" item for me. ;-)

Comment: @uhoh If you have access to a math library, Stillwell's Geometry of Surfaces is a very accessible introduction to the classification and geometry of surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to figure this out is to triangulate the polygon (add one vertex in the middle for simplicity. Then, the quotient space will have $2n$ triangles, and $3n$ edges. It will have the one central vertex, and so the gluings should somehow result in $n-1$ vertices. Whether this is true or not depends on how you do the gluing, but I leave the rest as an exercise.

Comment: *Thanks!* "Whether this is true or not depends on how you do the gluing" Does "when all pairs of opposite sides are joined" leave any options? Does the order of the gluing matter perahps? I'll give this some thought, but I'm thinking that the answer to my question is "Yes." Am I far off?

Comment: @uhoh Orient the edges counterclockwise. Then, every pair can be glued so the arrows agree or not. If they always agree, the euler characteristic will be $1,$ so you will NOT have a torus (you WILL have a projective plane). Notice that the standard identification for a square has the effect of sending all vertices to one, and even then you might blunder into a klein bottle. So, the answer is closer to "no" than to "yes".

Comment: Oh yes I see, got it. This is really helpful, I'll give this some thought now and keep an eye on the vertices. fyi I've corrected an error in the wording of the question but I don't think it impacts your answer. (side number $2n$ with $n \ge 2$) Also I found [Identifying the two-hole torus with an octagon](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1239104) but I don't think it's necessarily a duplicate as it is only for $n=4$.